# C# communicating windows application with browser extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I made **Firefox extension** but in that I **hard code one string parameter**, now I want that string parameter to be **dynamic**, so I plan to build **C# windows application** which will **write into text file** and then my **extension to read data from that text file**, but again I failure case, so is there any way to communicate  extension to outside world.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm), it is possible to read files using `OSFile`.

This is the basics of it:

```
let decoder = new TextDecoder();        // This decoder can be reused for several reads
let promise = OS.File.read("file.txt"); // Read the complete file as an array
promise = promise.then(
  function onSuccess(array) {
    return decoder.decode(array);        // Convert this array to a text
  }
);
```